# How to configure Hangfire dashboard to display jobs only from one queue?

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I have multiple Hangfire servers using shared database.  Each of this server handle its own queue and have dashboard configured. I wonder if it is possible to configure dashboard to display only jobs from specific queue.

Comment: Ooc, any findings since you asked?